# Magento store has home page url of just ip address and not actual domain name

Tags: magento

I am looking into a friend's site which is really old and strange, and it has one thing really weird with it. If you go to the site here: http://www.crystalvine.com and click on "products" on the top menu, it takes you to the store's home page which is set up in Magento.

Look at the url on that page. It is just an ip address. How could that be? Does anyone have any idea how to make it a domain name? I have access to the Magento account of that site, but can't figure out how to make the actual url show up.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System -> Configuration -> Unsecure -> Base URL 
&
System -> Configuration -> Secure -> Base URL

Put the full url in both those places: http://www.crystalvine.com

For good measure go to Index Management and Cache Management and refresh those.

Comment: If you are using a certificate, make sure to put https instead of http into the secure url box.